# Google docs live translation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-translate

I have a google doc in one language and need it to be translated.
i know  there's the  "Tools > Translate document" option, but that means i have to translate it manually every time i make a change.

is there a way for the translated doc to be in sync with the original doc, so that every time i make a change on the original doc, the translated doc will make the appropriate changes too?
in spreadsheet there's the `GOOGLETRANSLATE` function

i'm thinking it'd be possible thru an apps script command `LanguageApp.translate`
 but i don't know how to import that content from the original doc

---edit---
currently i have this script set on the destination document

```
function translate() {
var original = DocumentApp.openById('Oringinal document id');
var translated = LanguageApp.translate(original, 'zh', 'en');
Logger.log(translated);
return translated;
}
```

i'm not sure if it translated or what, the the log only shows document, i'm not sure how to get the content of the variable, i also don't know how to print the variable to the new document.
in triggers i only see time driven trigger? am i suppose to set the script on the original document?

Comment: In terms of possible, yes, you can take data from one document and pass it through the Translate API to another document for translation. But, Docs only has the `onOpen` trigger, not `onEdit` like a spreadsheet. So, you would need to manually trigger the script as you update the doc. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BrianBennett, i've added in what i've tried

Comment: Biggest thing is that the Translate API needs an object, not a document ID. So, there's some stuff you have to do before you can send/pull text for translating. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is proof of concept only. The script works, but won't keep formatting or images. Remember, there is no `onEdit` trigger for a Google Doc. You can create a custom time trigger, but if your doc isn't updated, it will continue to run in the background, which may or may not be desirable.

```js
// Grab the document body. No formatting, tables, etc are kept.
function getText() {
  var sourceDoc = DocumentApp.openById('idHere');
  var sourceBody = sourceDoc.getBody();

  // Push the body to an array for translating in the destination
  var array = [];
  array.push(sourceBody.getText());
  translateText(array);
}

// Take the array and translate to Spanish.
function translateText(e) {
  // Translate the array
  var es = LanguageApp.translate(e, 'en', 'es');

  // Open the doc to hold the translation
  var childDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

  // Clear out any previously-held text and then append the updated text from source.
  childDoc.getBody().clear();
  childDoc.getBody().appendParagraph(es);
}
```

This is rough, but it'll work if you add it to your child document and run from the script editor. You could also refactor it to work from the source and you push to a child document. It would also work to set a variable to hold the original ID of the document so you don't have to hard code it in with `PropertiesService`. Just some ideas to improve it. Don't forget that this will only grab the body text, none of the formatting.